# What are my options for working with markdown in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, markdown

I am seeing many many different use cases where I could use Markdown in apps that I write, both personal and professional.  But from my research so far, I haven't been able to find many options for working with it in ColdFusion.  I would certainly like to keep from reinventing the wheel by trying to implement it myself if someone else already has a project that I can use and contribute to, both because of time and not to duplicate efforts.

My preference would be to use an implementation in native coldfusion because that would be the easiest to tweak if it was necessary, but I am open to alternatives in other languages, as long as it is easy enough to implement and maintain.  I have looked at the [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) editor, but it doesn't look like it is the whole solution.  It would work for outputing the markup, but I would want to store that and then convert it to html as necessary for display.

Does anyone know of any other options?

Update: I do know of the [CFX_markdown](http://sebduggan.com/projects/cfxmarkdown) but I am not sure it is mature enough.  If anyone out there has experience with it I would love to hear about it.

Update 2: I have added a bounty to this question.  Not to say that the answer that has been given so far isn't a good one or isn't the best one, but I am wanting to see if anyone else has any other information about markdown with CF so we know all of the options.

Update 3: So offering the bounty didn't really work.  I will go ahead and let it auto accept the only answer just in case we have any late answers.  Thanks to everyone who has contributed.

Comment: As an aside, if there is not an already existing option or project out there to implement markdown in coldfusion, I would be interested in starting an open source implementation of it, if I could get some regex gurus to help.  I could do a lot of it I think, but having some help would make the work go faster I would think. Let me know if you may be interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Markdown Wiki](http://markdown.infogami.com/) refers to a Java implementation called [MarkdownJ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/markdownj/). I've no idea how mature it is, and I know you'd prefer a native ColdFusion implementation, but if you're running ColdfusionMX then a Java module might be a good compromise.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have looked a little into MarkdownJ, but like you I don't really know how mature it is.  Does anyone else have any experience with it?  I believe that is what the CFX_markdown is based on as well.

Comment: You can test MarkdownJ against the original script and several other implementations here: http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/?markdown=*This+**is+a+test*.&normalize=on

Comment: For future reference, I created a blog post showing how to use MarkdownJ in ColdFusion: http://bears-eat-beets.blogspot.com/2011/01/using-markdown-in-coldfusion.html

Answer (score 4):

We have a plugin created that does this in ColdFusion already:

http://coldbox.org/forgebox/view/Markdown

Comment: It looks like it has moved to: https://www.forgebox.io/view/commandbox-markdown and it looks like Luis is the one who wrote it.

Comment: Sorry I've downvoted this answer, but because it's just a link to a none existing URL, it's an incomplete answer.