# Lightweight markup language for Coldfusion

Tags: html, regex, coldfusion, markdown, markup

Is there a Lightweight markup language similar to the one I'm typing in that converts `*` to  *italics* and `**` to **bold** that works with coldfusion? or even a simpler version, that's just a list of regex rules and does that basics, like convert link markup to the a proper anchor?

Comment: This may be a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134989/what-are-my-options-for-working-with-markdown-in-coldfusion

Comment: right - didn't see that one

Comment: I'd recommend MarkdownJ; it's nice and easy to use, just createObject for the Java object, then call `MarkdownJ.markdown(Input)` and you get the HTML back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several CFML libraries to parse markdown to HTML: http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search#markdown